# Decrease retain count While ARC mode is Enabled

Tags: malloc, breakpoints, xcode4.6

I am new to iOS Developing , when I am using below code the retain count reaches to 3 and app will be crash,

```
 AsyncronousUIImage *image=[[AsyncronousUIImage alloc] init];
        [image loadImageFromURL:imageURL inImageView:templateView];
        image.delegate=self;
        [templateScroll addSubview:templateView];
```

[image]

I have ARC enable mode, I am using xcode 4.6.

getting the error:

malloc: *** error for object 0xa293dd0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Any Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARC, then the `image` will be released once it leaves the scope of the current function. It looks like you are using an asynchronous method with that variable. So, the image is released by the time the async code has received the data and is trying to set it.

When using ARC, you need to make sure that you are holding on to variables that are needed in other parts of your code, or at least pass them on to other objects that will hold on to them.

Comment: Can you please send me related links or sample code , i am new to iOS developing i cant Understand You Properly.

Comment: @Kunal Sure - here's the [ARC release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)